# How to combine layers before and after a base model and freeze some layers for base model?

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to:

1. Add a data augmentation before base model.
2. Freeze all layers in the base model except the last one.
3. Add additional layers after base model.

I have a simple function below, but the output doesn't look correct. I think I have 2 problems:

1. It outputs the output of data augmentation layer as (None, None, None, 3). Thus, the input of the MobilenetV3small is also (None, None, None, 3). Isn't it supposed to be (None, 224, 224, 3)?
2. The first output before model summary shows everything is trainable. model.summary()) however, indicates majority is Non-trainable params.

Here's my function.

```
def create_model(input_shape, output_shape):
    inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
    data_augmentation = Sequential([
        RandomBrightness(0.2),
        RandomContrast(0.2),
        RandomFlip(),
        RandomRotation(0.2),
        RandomHeight(0.2),
        RandomWidth(0.2),
        RandomTranslation(0.2, 0.2),
        RandomZoom(0.2, 0.2)
    ])
    x = data_augmentation(inputs)
    base_model = MobileNetV3Small(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', pooling="avg")
    for layer in base_model.layers[:-1]: layer.trainable = False
    x = base_model(x)
    extra =Sequential([
        Dense(256),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Activation("relu"),
        Dropout(0.2)
    ])
    x = extra(x)
    outputs =Dense(output_shape,activation='softmax')(x)
    model=Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(1e-3), loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
    layers = model.layers
    for i in range(len(layers)):
        if layers[i].trainable: print(i, layers[i].name, "Trainable:", layers[i].trainable, "Input:", layers[i].input_shape, "Output:", layers[i].output_shape)
    print(model.summary())
    return model
```

Here's the output.

```
0 input_1 Trainable: True Input: [(None, 224, 224, 3)] Output: [(None, 224, 224, 3)]
1 sequential Trainable: True Input: (None, 224, 224, 3) Output: (None, None, None, 3)
2 MobilenetV3small Trainable: True Input: (None, None, None, 3) Output: (None, 576)
3 sequential_1 Trainable: True Input: (None, 576) Output: (None, 256)
4 dense_1 Trainable: True Input: (None, 256) Output: (None, 5)
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0

 sequential (Sequential)     (None, None, None, 3)     0

 MobilenetV3small (Functiona  (None, 576)              939120
 l)

 sequential_1 (Sequential)   (None, 256)               148736

 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 5)                 1285

=================================================================
Total params: 1,089,141
Trainable params: 149,509
Non-trainable params: 939,632
_________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you made the last layer of `MobilenetV3small` trainable, its showing the whole block as trainable. You can print the individual layers in `MobilenetV3small` to check which layers are trainable.

```
for i in range(len(model_layers)):
    if i ==2:
       for layer in model_layers[i].layers:
           print(layer.name, layer.trainable)
```